# Color scatter plot points by x-values

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I want to color the points of a matplotlib scatterplot by their x-value. For example if x belongs to [0,5] then points are red, if (5,10] green, etc.

I tried to assign to the argument c list with colors but it doesn't work

`plt.plot(x_final, y_final, 'o', c=["r","g"])`

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) from [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) to make an array of *interval-based* colors :

```
colors = np.select( # feel free to adjust
    [(x_final >= 0) & (x_final <= 5),
     (x_final > 5) & (x_final <= 10)],
    ["r", "g"], default="k"
)

plt.scatter(x_final, y_final, c=colors, marker="P");
```

Output :

[image]

Used input :

```
np.random.seed(0)

x_final = np.linspace(1, 30, 50)
y_final = np.random.randn(50)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to easily handle an arbitrary number of cases:

```
import pandas as pd

colors = pd.cut(x_final,
                bins=[0, 5, 10, max(x_final)+1],
                labels=['g', 'r', 'k'], include_lowest=True).to_numpy()
plt.scatter(x_final, y_final, marker='o', c=colors)
```

Alternative with [`numpy.digitize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html):

```
colors = np.array(['g', 'r', 'k'])[np.digitize(x_final, [-0.01, 5, 10, np.inf],
                                               right=True)-1]
plt.scatter(x_final, y_final, marker='o', c=colors)
```

Example:

[image]

Comment: Always thinking outside the box ;)

Comment: @Timeless well `np.select` is also straightforward (if you don't have dozens of bins)

Comment: A `np.between` would made it cleaner/shorter.

Comment: @Timeless you can also use `np.digitize` ;)

Comment: You're crazy, I didn't know about this one ;)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way (not the best way, but simple to read and understand) of doing it includes the pre-computation of a list of `colors` based on the logic you have described. You can use a custom function (for more complex logic) or a simple for-loop like the following.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

x = list(range(13))
y = [random.randint(0, 5) for v in x] #some random Y values

colors = []
for v in x:
    if 0<=v<5:
        colors.append('red')
    elif 5<=v<10:
        colors.append('green')
    else:
        colors.append('black')
        
plt.scatter(x, y, c=colors)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if it's a dataframe you can use seaborn, assuming you have the columns x_final, y_final and category as columns in your dataframe (df_final):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(x='x_final', y='y_final', hue='category', data=df_final)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy and fast method would be to divide each x value by its  absolute maximum *(in case we have negative values as well)* and pass it as an argument to one of the RGB values in the color tuple:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(50)
y = x**2

for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.plot(x[i], y[i], 'o', color=(i/max(abs(x)), 0.1, 0.1))
```